# Server monitoring and trigger tool (pt-stalk)

Tags: linux, pt-stalk

Is there some equivalent tool to [pt-stalk](http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/2.1/pt-stalk.html) to monitor server load instead of MySQL on Linux machine?

Comment: What, specifically, are you trying to monitor? "server load" is a vague term (it could mean something as simple as load average, or it could mean a multivariate analysis of your system's overall workload)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my best knowledge no such tool exists for server level monitoring.

That being said it should not be hard to make one of yourself. For example you can use 'monit' which is lightweight monitoring tool with alarm on load and actions that should resolve this alarm.

What data to collect depends on your personal preferences but i would recommend:

- dmesg | tail -n 1000
- ps axwwww
- vmstat 5 5
- any relevant pieces of logs from your application
- netstat -antp
- ifconfig -a
- df
- maybe sar
- maybe 30 sec of network trafic (e.g. tcpdump)